# Oracle Database Trigger compilation issue

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make it so a database I've created can adjust to changes. I have an employee table where each row has a foreign key of another row in employee (this represents who each employee's manager is). What I want to do is make it so when I complete a transaction that swaps the job title of two employees, the foreign keys have the correct value after the transaction.

For example, if we have:

```
ID | jobTitle | fk
1    superboss  1
2    boss       1
3    lessboss   2
4    notboss    3
```

and we swap the job titles and foreign keys of notboss and less boss in a single transaction, we want the ending table to look like this:

```
ID | jobTitle | fk
1    superboss  1
2    lessboss   3
3    boss       1
4    notboss    2
```

The way I went about effecting these changes is by creating a trigger that fires when jobTitle is updated. It will find all the rows that have the previous foreign key and change it to the value of the fk in the row that has the old value of jobTitle. For some reason I'm getting a compilation error on my CREATE TRIGGER. I've posted my code below.

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeB
(
    employeeID integer,
    firstName varchar (255),
    lastName varchar (255),
    phone integer,
    jobTitle varchar (255),
    payGrade integer,
    fk_EmployeeemployeeID integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(employeeID),
    FOREIGN KEY(fk_EmployeeemployeeID) REFERENCES EmployeeB (employeeID) 
ON DELETE SET CASCADE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ManagerTrigger1A
AFTER UPDATE OF jobTitle ON employeeB 
REFERENCING OLD AS OldRow NEW AS NewRow  
BEGIN
UPDATE employeeB SET FK_EMPLOYEEEMPLOYEEID = (SELECT employeeID FROM employeeB WHERE jobTitle = :OldRow.jobTitle AND rownum <2) 
WHERE (SELECT employeeID FROM employeeB WHERE jobTitle = :OldRow.jobTitle) != null;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ManagerTrigger1B
AFTER UPDATE OF jobTitle ON employeeB 
REFERENCING OLD AS OldRow NEW AS NewRow  
BEGIN
DELETE FROM employeeB WHERE (SELECT employeeID FROM employeeB WHERE jobTitle = :OldRow.jobTitle) = null;
END;
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach to my problem, so if I'm going about this the wrong way or you have a better idea let me know. Either way, I'd still like to know why I'm getting this compilation error.

EDIT: Forgot the errors I was getting.

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ManagerTrigger1A
AFTER UPDATE OF jobTitle ON employeeB 
REFERENCING OLD AS OldRow NEW AS NewRow  
BEGIN
UPDATE employeeB SET FK_EMPLOYEEEMPLOYEEID = (SELECT employeeID FROM employeeB WHERE jobTitle = :OldRow.jobTitle AND rownum <2) 
WHERE (SELECT employeeID FROM employeeB WHERE jobTitle = :OldRow.jobTitle) != null;
END;
Error report:
ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers
04082. 00000 -  "NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers"
*Cause:    The trigger is accessing "new" or "old" values in a table trigger.
*Action:   Remove any new or old references.
```

Compilation errors:

```
Error(2,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(2,97): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "OLD"."MANAGER"."JOBTITLE": invalid identifier
```

Comment: This is not really a good design for many reasons.  Instead, create a relationship table where there is a parent child relationship with effective start/end dates.  Avoid triggers as much as possible. Go read this - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html  BTW, you did not show what your error is, or what line encountered.

Comment: A row-level trigger will not be able to modify anything other than the current row. If you try to update other row in the same table, Oracle will throw a `table mutating` exception.

Comment: I didn't know that... that makes this a whole lot harder. Any idea how I should go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the error it's hard to fix it, but you can try:

```
UPDATE employeeB SET FK_EMPLOYEEEMPLOYEEID = (SELECT employeeID FROM employeeB WHERE jobTitle = :OldRow.jobTitle AND rownum <2) 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT employeeID FROM employeeB WHERE jobTitle = :OldRow.jobTitle);
```

and

```
DELETE FROM employeeB WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT employeeID FROM employeeB WHERE jobTitle = :OldRow.jobTitle);
```

Comment: I tried 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ManagerTrigger1A
...  
BEGIN
UPDATE employeeB SET FK_EMPLOYEEEMPLOYEEID = (SELECT employeeID FROM employeeB WHERE jobTitle = :OldRow.jobTitle AND rownum <2) 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT employeeID FROM employeeB WHERE jobTitle = :OldRow.jobTitle);
END;
for the first trigger, but it came back with this error:

rror report:
ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers
04082. 00000 -  "NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers"
*Cause:    The trigger is accessing "new" or "old" values in a table trigger.

Comment: Use FOR EACH ROW in the trigger declaration. Check http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm